# what is wrong with this python code? the if block is not getting executed

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-module

I am writing a module, in which the email string is validated before it gets inserted into the db. When i try to enter invalid email string it prints else block with wrong email message but when i enter the correct email string it doesnt do anything. Here is the code:

```
   #!/usr/bin/python

import MySQLdb
import re
# Open database connection
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","root","acl" )

# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()

def addUser(email,password):
    
    try:
        if validateEmail(email):
            sql = "INSERT INTO acl_users(email, password) VALUES ('%s', '%s')" % (email, password)
                # Execute the SQL command
            cursor.execute(sql)
                # Commit your changes in the database
            db.commit()
        else:
            print "wrong email"
    except Exception as inst:
 # Rollback in case there is any error
    db.rollback()
    print inst

def validateEmail(email):

    if len(email) > 7:
        if re.match("^.+\\@(\\[?)[a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\.]+\\.([a-zA-Z]{2,3}|[0-9]{1,3})(\\]?)$", email) != None:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False
```

Any suggestions please?

## edit-1

got the answer guys! after creating instance of the exception in except block i got to know that import re was missing. that solved the problem.

Comment: Clearly, you're hiding a useful exception with your `try/except` block. This is exactly why you shouldn't catch all exceptions.

Comment: First, is there a reason you're using 1 and 0 instead of the Built in `True` and `False`?  It would help if we could see an example of the correct email.

Comment: well..you got a point I tried with it now. I have edited my question so you can check my latest code in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in validateEmail you use the module re, but you did not import it.

Answer (score -2):

I would print out the exception and see why it's failing.

Comment: This is more suitable in comment section.

Comment: hum sorry, yesterday I was told comments was bad form, if it was the answer. I'll figure it out :-) Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Is it possible that an exception is thrown in the if block? Put a print statement in the except block to check for that.

Also it's usually a bad idea to have a catch-all except block. If you're anticipating database errors then have a except block that catches them.

Comment: hmm... well...for the wrong email address the else block is getting printed...and the sql gets executed without the if else statement tho.